# Installing plyfile to Anaconda3

Tags: python

I run the following line from Spyder (Anaconda3):

```
 from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
```

and I get the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<ipython-input-269-2c796028388e>", line 1, in <module>
 from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
 ImportError: No module named 'plyfile'
```

Next I went to the Anaconda3 Scripts subdirectory and using the Windows Commander I wrote:

```
conda install plyfile
```

I received the following error message:

```
PackageNotFound: Package not found: "Package missing in current win 64     channels:
-plyfile
```

I made a search using the Google and I found the plyfile in the following address https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plyfile, but then I do not know what to do with it.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

`pip install plyfile`, if something isn't in the default anaconda repository but still a pypi package you can pip install and conda will still track the package within your environment.

Comment: I did install plyfile using pip and when I enter the command "from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement" in the Python 3.5 Shell the command is executed without problems.  But when I enter the same command in the Spyder console I get the error message: "Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<ipython-input-1-2c796028388e>", line 1, in <module>
    from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
  ImportError: No module named 'plyfile'

Comment: what is the output of `which spyder`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This worked for me.

```
sudo su
pip install plyfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I got plyfile to work in the Windows 10 Pro environment using Spyder 3.1.3, with a Python 2.7 environment on Anaconda as follows:

1. Open the plyfile.py program file in Spyder #This program is in the plyfile-05 file in the pkgs subdirectory of anaconda3.
2. Run the plyfile.py program in spyder3 and run "import plyfile" from the IPython console. #If you use the "from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement" statement you will get an error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' when you run a program that calls  PlyData or PlyElement.
3. Remove any import statement like "from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement" from the program you want to use plyfile in.  #Otherwise you will get the TypeError above when you run your program file.
4. Run your .py file now and the 3D figure should be generated.

Answer (score 0):

First activate the conda environment where you want to install the plyfile package

> > source activate environment_name

Then use pip to install the plyfile package

> > pip install plyfile

After that you can check whether the package has been installed in the same conda environment by using

> > conda list

Answer (score 0):

Find out executable used by Spyder or Jupyter

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

If its not using virtual environment executable

Setup ipykernal to use the virtual environment (*devconda*).

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=devconda
```

After this

```
sys.executable
```

> /opt/anaconda/envs/devconda/bin/python

And the pip imports will work in Jupyter or Spyder