# python 3.6.2 (anaconda3 5.0.0 64-bit) "pip install plyfile" failing

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda

I need to get `pip install plyfile` to succeed in my python 3.6.2 (anaconda3 5.0.0 64-bit) environment so that I can execute `from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement` in script to enable use of pca dimensional reduction algorithms.

I searched for "pip install plyfile" hits and found articles on this site, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735461/installing-plyfile-to-anaconda3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672864/cannot-install-plyfile-in-anaconda), that just comment on executing the command nothing that touches on the errors i'm seeing in screen grab below.

I executed `pip.exe search ply | findstr /r /i /c:"^ply"` and the result set contains a `plyfile (0.5)` entry so not sure why `pip install plyfile` is throwing errors and `conda install plyfile` failing to find it.

I tried issuing the pip.exe install command using the fully qualified path, e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\pip.exe" install plyfile`, and that doesn't change the result nor does executing it while having that directory as the current directory.

I tried installing current `Anaconda3-5.0.1-Windows-x86_64.exe` and `Anaconda3-5.0.1-Windows-x86.exe` distributions and then executing `c:\ProgramData\Scripts\pip.exe install plyfile` using those latest installs and I get the same result as below where it produces a bunch of error output.

I've captured the stdout with error details shown in first screen grab below, the last line of it being `TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'` if that points to something specific, and made it available [here](https://datascienceworksa.blob.core.windows.net/temp/pipInstallPlyfileError.txt).

Any suggestion from others who ran into this with current windows 10 [ v1709 fall creators update ] and anaconda3 5.0.0 x64 python 3.6.2 environment?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched on `TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'` and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-parse-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-transport-enco) SO q&a with fix being to execute `conda install pip` to update pip version. After that `pip install plyfile` worked as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pip` used by `conda` in Anaconda's Script folder.
Here are steps I would follow.

1) Open anaconda prompt or cmd prompt would do.

2) Try searching installed conda base and cd to Scripts. 
For e.g. on my laptop its in

```
 (base) c:\Anaconda3\Scripts>
```

3) Install using `pip install plyfile`

```
(base) c:\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install plyfile
Collecting plyfile
  Downloading plyfile-0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (fro
m plyfile)
Building wheels for collected packages: plyfile
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for plyfile ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\amandra\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\1a\76\bb\
6f25f1299f66e1e8b6ce9ad4ddcb8ed5730fd83b63375c41eb
Successfully built plyfile
Installing collected packages: plyfile
Successfully installed plyfile-0.5
```

4) Check if package is installed using

conda list

```
pkginfo                   1.4.1            py36hb0f9cfa_1
ply                       3.10             py36h1211beb_0
plyfile                   0.5                       <pip>
progress                  1.3              py36hbeca8d3_0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I am using, have tried, the pip.exe that comes with my anaconda install.  In my case it resides in %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts, e.g. I have tested changing to that director then executing as you say "pip install plyfile" and it throws the same errors as in the image I showed above where i'm using c:pip.exe to access that executable.

Comment: In your posting you seem to be running non `conda` `pip`. Did you try running from inside scripts folder or something like this? %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\pip install plyfile

Comment: Yes I've tried running the pip install command using the complete folder path to conda.exe folder pip.exe and also with that folder path being the current directory when the command is executed.  So in all cases i'm running %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\pip.exe which is sample folder path where my anaconda3 x64 conda.exe resides.